Connect iOS app with watch app in iPhone and not watchOS app
I am working on an application where we have different watch faces and when clicking on one of it we have to pass that face to the watch app in iPhone and make it the face of the Apple Watch paired with it.
Now I cracked the code where if the Apple Watch is paired then we can send the data but there are applications on App Store which connects directly with the watch app even if watch is not paired with the device.
WatchConnectivity framework session is showing reachable error as no watch is paired with it.
